# PHP difference between date and today (Show weeks)

Tags: php, strtotime

Ok, here is my problem. Instead of measuring 7 days in seconds, I want to count how many weeks (Sunday Through Saturday) there are from date #1 to today.

PHP

```
$today1 = date("Y-m-d");  

$diff = strtotime($date1,0) - strtotime($today1,0);
echo (floor($diff / 604800));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're counting in seconds, why use date() when you can use time() instead- it gives out the numeric time signature of your current time, making calculations such as this much easier.

Comment: Good point. I think I want to get away from seconds. And do 'This week' 'last week'

Comment: also if you want your week to say 0 when there is only 1 left, either subtract 1 echo (floor($diff / 604800)-1); or use an if statement.

Comment: "I think I want to get away from seconds" - no, you don't. It makes things more complicated (if not related to your immediate problem, then somewhere else in your application). Numbers are easier to crunch for computers. See the previous comment.

Comment: Ok, here is my problem. Instead of measuring 7 days in seconds, I want to count how many weeks (Sunday Through Saturday) there are from date #1 to today.

Comment: Look up the date function on php.net, however I think you are looking for something like this - $dayNum = (date("N")+1 == 8) ? 86400 : date("N")*86400;

Answer (score 1):

Using seconds is fine, perhaps try something like this:

```
$date1  = "2012-12-25";
$today1 = time();

$diff = strtotime($date1) - $today1;
if($diff < 604800) {
  $week = "this week";
} else {
  $week = (floor($diff / 604800) == 1) 
    ? floor($diff / 604800) . " week away" : floor($diff / 604800) . " weeks away";
}

echo $week;
```

Comment: That is closer to what I am looking for, but still does not differentiate between weeks (Sun - Sat)